# Win32 window fails to create?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window

I did my research but couldn't find an answer. The closest thing I found is "[Cannot create window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475131/cannot-create-window)", but it didn't help me. So, here it is!

**Basic info**

I have a static library and an application using a static library. I hooked up the application to the static library correctly (Include directories, library directories, actual library dependencies, etc). In the static library i have 1 file: `IWindow.h`. In the application I have 3 files: `Main.cpp`, `WindowMain.h` and `WindowMain.cpp`. `IWindow.h` defines an abstract window class:

```
#ifndef IWINDOW_H
#define IWINDOW_H

#include <Windows.h>

namespace NamespaceName
{
    template<class T>
    class IWindow
    {
    public:
        static LRESULT CALLBACK windowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

        virtual ~IWindow(){}

        virtual LRESULT handleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = 0;
        virtual VOID paint(HDC hDC) = 0;

        VOID create(HINSTANCE hI, LPCWSTR title, LPCWSTR className, DWORD dwStyle, DWORD dwExStyle = 0, int x = CW_USEDEFAULT, int y = CW_USEDEFAULT, int nWidth = CW_USEDEFAULT, int nHeight = CW_USEDEFAULT, HWND hWndParent = 0, HMENU hMenu = 0);

        HWND getHWND();
        BOOL isCreated();
    protected:
        HWND m_hWnd;
        BOOL created;
    };

    template<class T>
    LRESULT CALLBACK IWindow<T>::windowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        T* pThis = NULL;

        if(uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
        {
            CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
            pThis = (T*)pCreate->lpCreateParams;
            SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pThis);
        }
        else
        {
            pThis = (T*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        }

        if(pThis)
        {
            return pThis->handleMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        else
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    VOID IWindow<T>::create(HINSTANCE hI, LPCWSTR title, LPCWSTR className, DWORD dwStyle, DWORD dwExStyle = 0, int x = CW_USEDEFAULT, int y = CW_USEDEFAULT, int nWidth = CW_USEDEFAULT, int nHeight = CW_USEDEFAULT, HWND hWndParent = 0, HMENU hMenu = 0)
    {
        WNDCLASS windowClass = {0};
        windowClass.hInstance = hI;
        windowClass.lpszClassName = className;
        windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        windowClass.lpfnWndProc = IWindow::windowProc;

        RegisterClass(&windowClass);

        m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle, className, title, dwStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this);

        created = (m_hWnd ? TRUE : FALSE);
    }

    template<class T>
    HWND IWindow<T>::getHWND()
    {
        return m_hWnd;
    }

    template<class T>
    BOOL IWindow<T>::isCreated()
    {
        return created;
    }
}

#endif
```

Then,

`WindowMain.h` defines a subclass of `IWindow.h`

Code:

```
#ifndef WINDOWMAIN_H
#define WINDOWMAIN_H

#include <FolderName\Video\GUI\IWindow.h>

class WindowMain : public NamespaceName::IWindow<WindowMain>
{
public:
    ~WindowMain(){}

    LRESULT handleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    VOID paint(HDC hDC);
};

#endif
```

And,

it's accompanying .cpp file

completes it:

```
#include "WindowMain.h"

LRESULT WindowMain::handleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            hDC = BeginPaint(m_hWnd, &ps);

            FillRect(hDC, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
            paint(hDC);

            EndPaint(m_hWnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(m_hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

VOID WindowMain::paint(HDC hDC)
{
}
```

And finally,

the `Main.cpp`

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <GdiPlus.h>
#include "WindowMain.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WindowMain window;
    MSG msg;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    window.create(hInstance, L"Test Window", L"Test Window Class", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);

    if(!window.isCreated())
        return 1;

    ShowWindow(window.getHWND(), nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(window.getHWND());

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}
```

The `window.isCreated()` always returns `false`, thus making the `if` statement in the `Main.cpp` invert it to `true` and always returning 1 and exiting the application. If I omit the `if` statement from `Main.cpp` the window does not show up and the application goes on forever, until i force-stop it in the IDE.

**Additional questions (answer in comments if you want, these are optional and do not relate to the former question in any way)**

I don't like Visual Studio at all. I prefer using NetBeans so much more. I tried to use it for Windows programming but I failed. Do I have to use Visual Studio for Windows programming? Does it have some magical compiler that can compile Win32 programs in a special way? Or am I just doing something wrong?

What are these Gdiplus tokens and startup input? A link to somewhere that explains it would be awesome.

**Finally**

Thank you for taking your time to read this, and potentially trying to help me. If you need any more information I'll be happy to provide it. If the question was poorly constructed please let me know how to improve it and I will. ;)

**Edit #1**

Found this: "[Win32 API window won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080129/win32-api-window-wont-open?rq=1)", just for the record, it didn't help my case either.

**Edit #2**

In `IWindow.h`, when I was creating a `WNDCLASS`, for the window process, I tried to use `T::windowProc` instead of `IWindow::windowProc`, but it didn't help either.

**Edit #3**

Found "[WinAPI window doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541953/winapi-window-doesnt-appear?rq=1)", but didn't help either.

**Edit #4**

"Try setting windowClass.cbWndExtra to sizeof(LONG_PTR) before registering the class." -suggestion from the comments. Tried it too, and also didn't help.

**Edit #5**

Tried replacing `WNDCLASS` with `WNDCLASSEX` and `RegisterClass` with `RegisterClassEx` and added `windowClassEx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)` (I changed the variable name from `windowClass` to `windowClassEx` too), but didn't help either...

Comment: I don't actually use VS for Windows programming all too often, so no.

Comment: Okay, thanks for info, I'll do some more research for it then. I am so glad i don't have to use it :P

Comment: Try setting windowClass.cbWndExtra to sizeof(LONG_PTR) before registering the class.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, tried it, but didn't help :/

Comment: You need to add a HWND as a parameter to handleMessage and pass it the HWND from windowProc. And of course, use the new HWND for painting and the DefWindowProc

Comment: I dont' need it when i have m_hWnd. I only need HWND in the static windowProc to find out which of the subclasses called it (if there are multiple windows) and then extract it from the CREATESTRUCT and just pass the message to the handle message. The handle message then uses m_hWnd, which is the same as the HWND passed to the static function.

Comment: Ah, but for the first few window messages, you don't have m_hWnd yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see at least two errors.

First, you register the class with

```
windowClass.hInstance = hI;
```

but when you create the window, you pass a different `HINSTANCE`:

```
m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle, className, title, dwStyle, x, y,
          nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this);
//                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `HINSTANCE` parameters must match in order for the class to be found. You should use `hI` in both places.

Second, your code uses the `m_hWnd` member before it is initialized.

```
return DefWindowProc(m_hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

When the window receives the `WM_NCCREATE` message, `m_hWnd` has not yet been initialized. It doesn't get initialized until the `CreateWindowEx` returns. You need to get the correct window handle to `DefWindowProc`. One way is to pass the `hWnd` parameter from `windowproc` through to `handlemessage`. Another is to add

```
m_hWnd = hWnd;
```

in your `if(uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)`.

Notice that your code assumes that if `GWLP_USERDATA` is nonzero, then `m_hWnd` is valid. However, you did nothing to actually make this assumption valid. Between the receipt of the `WM_NCCREATE` message and the completion of `CreateWindowEx`, you have a nonzero `GWLP_USREDATA` but `m_hWnd` is not initialized.

The way to debug this is to set a breakpoint on your window procedure and step through it. When stepping through the handling of the `WM_NCCREATE` message, you should have noticed that `m_hWnd` is not initialized.

There is a third bug in this code, which you would eventually stumble across once you get the window created: You never set `m_hWnd` back to `NULL` when the window is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks so much! This did help solve the problem and I have no idea how I missed those things! Should pay more attention in the future I guess :P